# getting the index of the items in the array

Tags: java, inheritance, printing, while-loop, java.util.scanner

If I added two Items to my array list, and these tow Items have the same name, when I want to print them out they will have the same index as when I invoked the method indexOf() it will return index of first occurrence of theElement, what is the best way to get the index of the Items, I ve tried to declare a local variable and assgin the value of the counter to it and in the print statement I just added -- and It did work but I think It should be a better way of doing it

```
public class Example 
{


      public void checkIndex(int index)
       {
          if (index < 0 || index >= size) // smaller 
             throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
                 ("index = " + index + "  size = " + size);
       }

       public Object get(int index)
       {
          checkIndex(index);
          return element[index];
       }


       public int indexOf(Object theElement)
       {
          // search element[] for theElement
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
             if (element[i].equals(theElement))
                return i;

          // theElement not found
          return -1;
       }   

}

    public class Array extends Example

    {
       protected void printList()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            if(super.size() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("List is Empty.");
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("\nShowing List: ");
                while(counter < super.size())
                {
                    String s = (counter+1) + "\t" + super.get(counter).toString();

                   System.out.println(s + " the index is: " + super.indexOf(super.get(counter)));

                }
            }
            System.out.println();  // this is to sprate the the options from the result.
        }
    }
```

Comment: ArrayList.indexOf will work as long as you are not using primitives, and if you are you could just use the class (ie int and Integer)

Comment: @TAAPSogeking That's either unclear or inaccurate... The question is asking about its own implementation of IndexOf, no ArrayList.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not sure if I am understanding. Do you want us to find the problem in your code or just offer a solution to the problem of duplicate naming?

Comment: @mohamedghassar did you get it done? is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

You could design your class in a way to provide the following:

```
IndexOf(object obj) // giving index of first occurrence

IndexOf(object obj, int startIndex) // giving index of first occurrence after the specified index
```